# Using Pandas to convert API response to single CSV row

Tags: python, pandas, api, csv, format

I'm looping through a list of domains to gather info on and I'd like to convert an API response into a single CSV row and I'm having trouble getting things in the right format. Here is an example of the API response:

```
[
   {
      "domainName":"something I made up.com",
      "resourceType":"web",
      "ipv4":"34.102.136.180",
      "geolocation":{
         "city":"The Greenhouse",
         "country":"US",
         "latitude":"37.41889",
         "longitude":"-122.10361",
         "postalCode":"",
         "region":"California",
         "timezone":"-07:00"
      },
   {
      "domainName":"somethingimadeup.com",
      "resourceType":"ns",
      "ipv4":"34.102.136.180",
      "geolocation":{
         "city":"The Greenhouse",
         "country":"US",
         "latitude":"37.41889",
         "longitude":"-122.10361",
         "postalCode":"",
         "region":"California",
         "timezone":"-07:00"
      },
   {
      "domainName":"ns03.domaincontrol.com",
      "resourceType":"www.web",
      "ipv4":"97.74.101.2",
      "geolocation":{
         "city":"Sweetwater Ranch",
         "country":"US",
         "latitude":"33.60421",
         "longitude":"-111.8882",
         "postalCode":"",
         "region":"Arizona",
         "timezone":"-07:00"
      },
]
```

**into something like this:**

| domain | Resource Type | ipv4 | Resource Type | ipv4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| example.com | web | 34.102.136.184 | ns | 34.102.136.184 |

I've been trying to figure it out with Pandas but not having much luck, I'm also not sure how to address each response having a different amount of resources, ie, more than one NS, can anyone help? I'm still learning python and that's not exactly what management heard.

I can share my code but it's just a for loop targeting the domain column that exists in the input csv at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json library to parse it, along with pandas' to_csv method to save it.

Example:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

api_response = ...

parsed = json.loads(api_response) # Parse the api response
df = pd.DataFrame(parsed[0]) # Index the first result and create a dataframe with it

with open("output.csv", "w+") as f: # Create a output.csv file
    df.to_csv(f) # Write the csv data to the file
```